# ¿Qué significa engomado ecológico?

Tags: significado, méxico

En relacion a coches yo creo, que es engomado ecológico. Veo carteles y advertencias en todas partes. ¿Es una revisa general quizá? http://m.netnoticias.mx/2018-02-14-c2793435/puntos-a-considerar-para-obtener-el-engomado-ecologico/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creo que se ha de tratar de un tipo de certificación que muestra que el coche no va a contaminar demasiado el medio ambiente, y el pequeño certificado se va a pegar, o engomar, al parabrisas.

Otro artículo que aclara esto un poco más: http://www.conduccioneficiente.tv/tag/engomado-ecologico/

Una imagen:

[image: parabrisas con un joven que coloca el engomado]

Answer (score 3):

Con la imagen de aparente001 ya nos queda a todos claro qué es un **engomado**.
Pero por completitud, un poco de respaldo de los diccionarios de nuestras academias.

Mencionar que en España no se emplea habitualmente el término para designar ese elemento. El equivalente se suele denominar "la **pegatina** de la ITV" [Inspección Técnica de Vehículos]. Una de las cosas que supuestamente garantiza portarla en el parabrisas es que tu vehículo contamina dentro de unos niveles establecidos por el gobierno, lo cual supongo que implica el adjetivo "ecológico" en su versión mexicana.

Comenta @alvalongo que en Colombia se conoce como **calcomanía**.

La acepción de **engomado** que aparece en el DRAE no se corresponde con el elemento de la foto

[**engomado, da**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FNxc1en)

> Del part. de engomar.
>
> 1. adj. C. Rica, Méx., Nic. y Pan. Dicho de una persona: Que amanece con goma (‖ resaca).
> 2. adj. Méx. Peripuesto, acicalado.
> 3. m. Acción y efecto de engomar.

Pero sí aparece en el Diccionario de Mexicanismos de la Academia Mexicana

[image: engomado]

Según el DRAE

**[calcomanía](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6kWuiX2)**

> Del fr. décalcomanie.
>
> 1. f. Procedimiento que consiste en pasar de un papel a objetos diversos de madera, porcelana, seda, etc., imágenes coloridas
>      preparadas con trementina. La calcomanía no figura entre las bellas
>      artes.
> 2. f. **Imagen obtenida por calcomanía**.

Comment: El elemento que en la foto que envió @aparente001 se está poniendo en el panorámico del vehículo se conoce en Colombia como **calcomanía**.

Comment: @alvalongo Parece que en México también se conoce como calcomanía a la par que como engomado. No estoy seguro. De todas formas, incluyo tu comentario en el texto de la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

En México, un engomado no es más que una calcomanía. Veamos la definición del [Diccionario del Español de México](http://dem.colmex.mx/):

> **Engomado**
>
> **3: s. m.** Etiqueta cuyo reverso tiene pegamento o goma para adherirlo a una superficie lisa

En la nota que refieres, el **engomado ecológico** es la calcomanía que recibes después de la inspección vehicular y que acredita que tu coche cumple con las normas ambientales para Ciudad Juárez, en Chihuahhua. En Ciudad de México, por ejemplo, el **engomado vehicular** es una calcomanía que recibes cuando tramitas las matrículas y que debes colocar en el vidrio trasero; es de un color específico e indica qué días —en caso de contingencia ambiental— no puedes usar tu coche.